# Loop through a dataframe that is a result of groupby

Tags: python, ipython

```
      df2 = df.groupby('ActualDebugData')['HardwareId'].count().to_frame(name='df1')
```

The output of dataframe df2 is:

```
      ActualDebugData    df1

      Bell               3212
      Bell Mobile        514
```

I would like to loop through the df2 and state that both Bell and Bell mobile are the same and hence add its corresponding df1's.

Final output has to be

```
      Bell               3726
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you know they are the same? Is it because the first word is the same?  What is the logic you would like to use to determine "identical" records

Comment: @flyingmeatball: I have a predefined list that states that Bell and Bell Mobility are same, Telus and Telus Mobility are same, Rogers and Rogers At&T wireless are same.

Comment: Edited my response below to reflect your comment.  It would be easier to help if you posted a df representing the raw data in question, not just the grouping code you used.

Comment: @flyingmeatball: It works perfectly fine. 
df['ActualDebugData_list'] = df['ActualDebugData'].str.split(' ')
df['ActualDebugData_updated'] = df['ActualDebugData_list'].apply(lambda x: x[0] if type(x) == list else x)

In ActualDebugData_updated, I have two values  'T-Mobile' and 'T-mobile'. These two strings represent the same carrier, because of the lower case 'm', it does not group properly.  Please let me know is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Make everything capitol letters before you do this.  df['ActualDebugData'] = df['ActualDebugData'].str.upper()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you group you could run something like this, assuming you're splitting on spaces:

```
df['HardwareId_list'] = df['HardwareId'].str.split(' ')
df['hardware_updated'] = df['HardwareId_list'].apply(lambda x: x[0] if type(x) == list else x)
```

Then you could group as you had been doing.

**EDIT PER COMMENT ABOVE**

If you have a list, apply that list first as a mapping, THEN do the grouping.